# Page url changes but not able to access content on the page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created an API to logout:

```
// Logout

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();
    res.render('Some logout page.ejs');
});
```

This API basically logs out and renders the logout page.

So on click of a button :

```
<Link to={`/logout`}>Logout</Link>
```

or

```
<Button onclick={logoutfunction}/>

logoutfunction = () => {
return Redirect to = "/logout />
}
```

The url redirects to :

```
 localhost:3001/logout
```

But return an empty page.

But when I press the enter button on the URL it successfully logs out rendering the logout page.

So how to on click of a button not just redirect to the URL but also access the API in React hooks?

I have tried different solutions but don't seem to be working on any of them.

Let me know if any other details are required.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you're using Link component. Are u working with react? If so,
logout page should be in browser router (react-dom-router), not on server router
What you're doing seems like adding router into the server.

Even if my answer works for you, don't call API like that because react app doesn't work like that.

Instead of doing that, you can access your API server by axios, fetch, some kind of Ajax calling.

Comment: actually its ejs file only.
But my issue is that its not reaching the api. Only the url is changed to /logout but when i go to browser url and hit enter then only I am able to access the api

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: You are right but when i try to access as 

axios.get(`/auth/logoutPage`).then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })

It gives error...too many redirect.... but doesnot reach the api.also same error while using useeffect to call api

Comment: Can you share the API calling parts? Do you manipulate the redirect in server-side? If so stop doing that. you better go with `axios.get('/logout').then(res =>{ //do something with it history.push('/any/route' )})`

Comment: API to logout:: 

    router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
        req.logOut();
    });
Route to call api: auth/logout
In react I'm calling this API as:

    axios.get(`/auth/logout`).then((res) => {
                    console.log('im inside)
                })

So when I'm calling API as such shouldn't the Logout API be triggered and logout of that session.

Or is there that I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: To find out what you've done wrong, you can share the react page component and server side code at least briefly into your question using code block. currently, your code looks fine. But something gotta be wrong.